# twitter-bootstrap-rails gem + Snapchat icon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, twitter-bootstrap-rails, snapchat

I am trying to implement Snapchat Font Awesome icon in my Rails app. To implement Bootstrap I have installed `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem.

I am able to implement Facebook Font Awesome icon using `<i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-2x"></i>`, but `<i class="fa fa-snapchat-square fa-2x"></i>` does not display anything.

Comment: Check the version of fontawesome included in your project. `fa-snapchat-square` has been added only recently in version 4.6

Comment: @Slava.K thanx for you comment. I checked and found that the version used by _twitter-bootstrap-rails_ gem has 4.4.0 version of font awesome. So i wanted to ask that is there any way to update font awesome version in  _twitter-bootstrap-rails_ gem?

Comment: you can fork twitter-bootstrap-rails gem on github, update dependency there and then include it in your Gemfile:
`gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => "your fork url here"`

Comment: @Slava.K I tried that. But the latest version of fontawesome in _twitter-bootstrap-rails_ is 4.4.0. So I had to use _font-awesome-rails_ gem.